# Turn off "RHINO USAGE WARNING" for HtmlUnit

Tags: htmlunit, rhino

I'm using HtmlUnit 2.27 and I currently have the following settings

```
    LogFactory.getFactory().setAttribute("org.apache.commons.logging.Log",
            "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit").setLevel(Level.OFF);
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.commons.httpclient").setLevel(Level.OFF);
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter")
            .setLevel(Level.OFF);
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.ActiveXObject")
            .setLevel(Level.OFF);
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.html.HTMLDocument")
            .setLevel(Level.OFF);
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript").setLevel(Level.OFF);
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.WindowProxy")
            .setLevel(Level.OFF);
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(Level.OFF);
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache").setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

But I am still getting Rhino warnings such as below.

```
RHINO USAGE WARNING: Missed Context.javaToJS() conversion:
Rhino runtime detected object
```

Anyway to prevent Rhino warnings to be printed?

Comment: This msg usually points to. a HtmlUnit error. Please open an issue and add a minimal test case.

Comment: no bug report so far, i guess you are no longer interested in getting this fixed....

Comment: @RBRi I've been very busy with work, I will post one as soon as things slow down with my work